# Number of multi-indices

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $k=(k_1,\ldots,k_d) \in \mathbb{N}^d$ be a $d$-dimensional multiindex with 
$$
|k|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^d k_j \quad \text{ and } \quad |k|_\infty = \max_{j=1}^d k_j .
$$

How can I bound cardinality of the set 
$$
\{k \in \mathbb{N}^d: |k|_1 = J \text{ and } |k|_\infty > Q \}
$$
i.e. all multi indices on a certain diagonal that are not contained in a cube of length Q ?

Thanks!

edit: $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,\ldots\}$.
Moreover, it holds that $\sum_{|k|_1 = J} 1 = \binom{J-1}{d-1}$, but I have no idea how to incorporate the second condition regarding the $\infty$-norm of $k$.

Comment: Does your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ contain $0$ ?
Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) could provide an easy upperbound.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ excludes the zero. I edited the question.